# Amazon CloudFront - Inavalidating files by regex, e.g. *.png

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

Is there a way to have Amazon CloudFront invalidation (via the management console), invalidate all files that match a pattern? e.g. images/*.png

context -

1. I had set cache control for images on my site, but by mistake left out the png extension in the cache directive on Apache. So .gif/.jpg files were cached on users computer but .png files WERE not.
2. So I fixed the apache directive and now my apache server serves png files with appropriate cache control directives. I tested this.
3. But the cloudfront had in past fetched those png files, SO hitting those png files via cloudfront still brings those png files with NO cache control. End Result - still no user caching for those png files
4. I tried to set the invalidation in Amazon CloudFront console as images/*.png. The console said completed, but I still do not get cache control directive in png files. --> Makes me believe that the invalidation did not happen.
5. I can set the invalidation for the complete image directory; but then I have too many image files --> I would get charged > $100 for this. So trying to avoid this.
6. Changing image versions so that cloudfront fetches new versions is a painful exercise in my code; doing it for say 500 png files would be a pain. --> Trying to avoid it.
7. Listing individual png files is also a pain --> trying to avoid it as well.

Thanks,
-Amit

Answer (score 2):

If your CloudFront distribution is configured in front of an S3 bucket, you can list all of the objects in the S3 bucket, filter them with a regex pattern (e.g., `/*.png/i`), then use that list to construct your invalidation request.

That's what I do anyway. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Are you even sure of this? [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects-paths) say that patterns can only be assigned by * at the end of the path